# Trying to create a gcloud cloud run service, it says "Cloud Run is not available in the regions allowed by your organization. "

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-run

I am trying to create a simple test cloud run service, when creating the service via the UI once I click 'create service' it says

1. Cloud Run (fully managed) **"Cloud Run is not available in the regions allowed by your organization. "**
2. Cloud run for Anthos

Why am I not able to create a cloud run fully managed service?

Comment: Cloud Run is currently only available in these regions ... https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/locations  ... the message implies that your organization (of which your project is a child) has constrained regions allowed to be used.

Comment: @Kolban but where do I edit this? my organization name is 'no organization' and I can't seem to find anything regarding this.  Most settings I see are project specific.

Comment: Ok so I enabled the cloud run API and now it works.  That's a strange error that they gave me, made no sense.

Comment: thank you for your last post.  I agree that does sound like a stranger error ... but thanks to you, the next person who runs across it can find this post and have progress made because of your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably, you have to enable Cloud Run.
In the Marketplace page, search with "Cloud Run".

Answer (score 2):

This is due to an issue with Cloud Run.

Until it is resolved, you need to manually enable the Cloud Run API at https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google-cloud-platform/cloud-run

Comment: Awesome. Do you know if this issue is documented anywhere?

Comment: This issue should be fixed by the end of the week. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of all the available regions and resources available for [Cloud Run for Anthos](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/#available)

And for [Cloud Run (Fully Managed)](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/locations) the available regions are (as of 2020-01-08):

- asia-northeast1 (Tokyo)
- europe-west1 (Belgium)
- us-central1 (Iowa)
- us-east1 (South Carolina)

You will have to contact the responsible person in the organization under which your project exists to remove the restriction on at least one of the supported regions before you can use Cloud Run.

Comment: I recommend not listing regions as they're likely to go out of date.

Answer (score 0):

The error message has nothing to do with the underlying problem. I discovered in newly created projects you need to activate Compute by accessing it in the console and then waiting a few minutes.